# Dynamic Named Range not recalculating when using .ClearContents

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a simplified example:

I have contiguous data in A1:E10.

I have a Dynamic Named Range (scope = workbook) defined by the following formula:

```
DynRange =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1))
```

I then run the following VBA code:

```
Dim dynrng As Range 
Set dynrng = ThisWorkbook.Names("DynRange").RefersToRange
Range("A8:E10").Delete xlUp
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Names("DynRange").RefersToRange.rows.Count
MsgBox dynrng.rows.Count

Range("A7:E10").FillDown '(just adding the data back for our next case below)
```

Both message boxes return 7: i.e. the workbook named range and the VBA range variable we set to it both update as the data is modified.

Now I run the same code but with `.ClearContents` (or `.Clear`) instead of `.Delete`:

```
Dim dynrng As Range 
Set dynrng = ThisWorkbook.Names("DynRange").RefersToRange
Range("A8:E10").ClearContents 
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Names("DynRange").RefersToRange.rows.Count
MsgBox dynrng.rows.Count
```

The first message box returns 7, but the second returns 10.

Why is the VBA range variable not updating along with the workbook named range in the second case?

(calculation is set to automatic, and I tried `Application.Calculate`)

Thanks in advance for any illumination!

Comment: You aren't by chance dealing with how to find the last row, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Name.RefersToRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name.referstorange) returns a `Range` object. Once you have

```
Set dynrng = ThisWorkbook.Names("DynRange").RefersToRange
```

`dynrng` no longer has any reference to the named range, it is simply equivalent to

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:E10")
```

If you delete rows, then the `Range` object is affected accordingly.

If you clear contents, `Sheet1.Range("A1:E10")` still has 10 rows.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense.
Is there a way to tie a variable to the workbook named range object so that it does update dynamically?

Comment: Can you explain more what you're trying to do, and what the context is? There may be another way.

Comment: I want to do stuff with the data, modify it (remove records, add records), and then do more stuff with it. I guess I can re-set the range each time I modify... but I just figured since the workbook named range recalculates automatically each time the data is modified, I should be able to do something similar with VBA (without calling external functions/manually re-setting the range).

Comment: Can you use a table? (Ctrl+T)?

Comment: Hmm... yes that might work. Thanks Ben - much appreciated!